# Extract and count pairs of adjacent numbers within rows

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

I wish to extract "pair of numbers", i.e. numbers in adjacent columns within the same row. Then I want to count the pairs to determine which are most frequent.

As example I created a dataset with 5 columns and 4 rows:

```
var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
   1    2    3    0   11
   2    0    3    0    1
   3    0    3    1    2
   4    1    2    2   11
```

The most frequent consecutive pairs of number are:

`1 -> 2`: 3 times (row 1, var1 -> var2; row 3, var4 -> var5; row 4, var2 -> var3)

`3 -> 0`: 3 times (row 1, var3 -> var4; row 2, var3 -> var4; row 3, var1 -> var2)

`0 -> 3`: 2 times

I am struggling with the code that identifies the most frequent 'consecutive pair of numbers'?

How can I replace the identified consecutive pair of number with 2 and the others with 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `base` alternative.

**1. Find and count pairs**

Because you only have numerical values, we coerce data to matrix. This will make subsequent calculations considerably faster. Create lag and lead versions (column-wise) of the data, i.e. remove the last column (`m[ , -ncol(m)]`) and first column (`m[ , -ncol(m)]`) respectively.

Coerce the lag and lead data to 'from' and 'to' vectors, and count pairs (`table`). Convert table to matrix. Select first pair with max frequency.

```
m <- as.matrix(d)
tt <- table(from = as.vector(m[ , -ncol(m)]), to = as.vector(m[ , -1]))
m2 <- cbind(from = as.integer(dimnames(tt)[[1]]),
            to = rep(as.integer(dimnames(tt)[[2]]), each = dim(tt)[1]),
            freq = as.vector(tt))      
m3 <- m2[which.max(m2[ , "freq"]), ]
# from   to freq 
#    3    0    3
```

If you want *all* pairs with maximum frequency, use `m2[m2[ , "freq"] == max(m2[ , "freq"]), ]` instead.

---

**2. Replace values of most frequent pair and set rest to zero**

Make a copy of the original data. Fill it with zero. Grab the 'from' and 'to' values of the 'max pair'. Get indexes of matches in lag and lead data, which correspond to 'from' columns. `rbind` with indexes of 'to' columns. At the indexes, replace zeros with 2.

```
m_bin <- m
m_bin[] <- 0
ix <- which(m[ , -ncol(m)] == m3["from"] &
              m[ , -1] == m3["to"],
            arr.ind = TRUE)
m_bin[rbind(ix, cbind(ix[ , "row"], ix[ , "col"] + 1))] <- 2
m_bin
#      var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
# [1,]    0    0    2    2    0
# [2,]    0    0    2    2    0
# [3,]    2    2    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

---

**3. Benchmark**

I use data of a size somewhat similar to that mentioned by OP in comment: a data frame with 10000 rows, 100 columns, and sampling from 100 different values.

I compare the code above (`f_m()`) with the `zoo` answer (`f_zoo()`; functions below). To compare the output, I add `dimnames` to the `zoo` result.

The result shows that `f_m` is considerably faster.

```
set.seed(1)
nr <- 10000
nc <- 100
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100, nr * nc, replace = TRUE),
                          nrow = nr, ncol = nc))

res_f_m <- f_m(d)
res_f_zoo <- f_zoo(d)
dimnames(res_f_zoo) <- dimnames(res_f_m)

all.equal(res_f_m, res_f_zoo)
# [1] TRUE

system.time(f_m(d))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.12    0.01    0.14 

system.time(f_zoo(d))
# user  system elapsed 
# 61.58   26.72   88.45

f_m <- function(d){
  m <- as.matrix(d)
  tt <- table(from = as.vector(m[ , -ncol(m)]),
              to = as.vector(m[ , -1]))
  m2 <- cbind(from = as.integer(dimnames(tt)[[1]]),
              to = rep(as.integer(dimnames(tt)[[2]]),
                       each = dim(tt)[1]),
              freq = as.vector(tt))

  m3 <- m2[which.max(m2[ , "freq"]), ]
  m_bin <- m
  m_bin[] <- 0
  ix <- which(m[ , -ncol(m)] == m3["from"] &
                m[ , -1] == m3["to"],
              arr.ind = TRUE)
  m_bin[rbind(ix, cbind(ix[ , "row"], ix[ , "col"] + 1))] <- 2
  return(m_bin)
}


f_zoo <- function(d){
  pairs <- sort(table(c(rollapply(t(d), 2, toString))))
  top <- scan(text = names(tail(pairs, 1)), sep = ",", what = 0L, quiet = TRUE)
  right <- rollapplyr(unname(t(d)), 2, identical, top, fill = FALSE)
  left <- rbind(right[-1, ], FALSE)
  t(2 * (left | right))
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your help yes it works;congrats one more question what would be the best way to plot m2? Also (i didn't tried this) I was wondering at step 2 how to modify the code to replace specific pairs of numbers (eg. not the frequent ones; pairs selected after step 1 )?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! (1) "the best way to plot m2":it's a rather broad and opinion-based question, depending on which message you wish to convey. A very general answer is that counts are often visualized with a bar plot. You need to be more specific.

Comment: (2) "replace specific pairs" Specific based on what? The values of 'to' and 'from'? If so, use your desired condition(s) for replacement of row values in `i`*. E.g. replace rows where 'from' is 2, and 'to' is 5 in this matrix `m <- matrix(1:6, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("from", "to")))`, `m[m[ , "from"] == 2 & m[ , "to"] == 5] <- 0`. *Please study `?Extract` _carefully_. That's the single most important help page for understanding data manipulation in R. See also [Subsetting in Hadleys book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html). Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your code and thank you for explaining the code. As, I am beginner in R I try to improve the first part of the code "find and count pairs". I tried  to count the most frequent elements that occurs consecutively 3 times in a row., but I receive the subscript out out of bound error. Also I tried the tally code. If you have time could you help me please. Thanks

Comment: @RforDummies Without seeing (a) the code or (b) the data or (c) the desired output, it is unfortunately impossible to help you.

Comment: one solution would be threeNumbers <- sort(table(c(rollapply(t(m), 3, toString))))

Comment: @ but how to use dimnames[tt] in your case? If you have time/patient could you suggest something please?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(zoo)
pairs <- sort(table(c(rollapply(t(DF), 2, toString))))

# all pairs with their frequency
pairs
##  0, 1 0, 11  2, 0 2, 11  2, 2  2, 3  3, 1  4, 1  0, 3  1, 2  3, 0 
##     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     3     3 

# same but as data.frame
data.frame(read.table(text = names(pairs), sep = ","), freq = c(pairs))
##       V1 V2 freq
## 0, 1   0  1    1
## 0, 11  0 11    1
## ...
## 0, 3   0  3    2
## 1, 2   1  2    3
## 3, 0   3  0    3

# pair with highest frequency - picks one if there are several
tail(pairs, 1)
## 3, 0 
##    3 

# all pairs with highest frequency
pairs[pairs == max(pairs)]
## 1, 2 3, 0 
##    3    3
```

To replace all 3,0 pairs with 2 and everything else with 0:

```
top <- scan(text = names(tail(pairs, 1)), sep = ",", what = 0L, quiet = TRUE)
right <- rollapplyr(unname(t(DF)), 2, identical, top, fill = FALSE)
left <- rbind(right[-1, ], FALSE)
t(2 * (left | right))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    0    0    2    2    0
## [2,]    0    0    2    2    0
## [3,]    2    2    0    0    0
## [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "1     2     3   0    11
2     0     3   0     1
3     0     3   1     2
4     1     2   2     11"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```